# adding dynamic icon/image using MVXImageView to item in MvxListView using MVVMCross Xamarin Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

We have implemented solution using below plugins but thats not working

```
MvvmCross.Plugin.DownloadCache
MvvmCross.Plugin.File
```

also later we tried some sample that implemented above 2 plugins that works but only work in that sample with 5.1.1 specific version if we upgrade that then it won't work
also we uses latest version of MVVMCross framework where that MVVMCross.platform deprecated so we can't use that also latest version using above plugin gave us inflated class error in MVXIMageview.

please provide any other solution that will help us to add icons like below screen, you will see below blue line indicated the same

We are using MVXListview to show items and we have to add that icon to item

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use Glide, Nuke, Akavache or whatever to load the images.

If these are local icons, you can still use MvvmCross bindings to bind the images.

On Android you have these target bindings:

- DrawableName
- DrawableId
- ResourceName
- AssetImagePath
- Bitmap

We don't have any on iOS though, but you could easily do something similar exposing a property on your cell that sets an image from the bundle.

Comment: I guess solution not feasible, we need dynamic icon using MVX control, see if able to share code snippet for the same, thanks

Comment: I don't understand what you think is not feasible. What is it that you cannot do? You are being super vague.

Comment: Sorry let me correct my word feasible in the sense, local icons will be applied to all items in the list but we have requirement of adding based on type of item, lets say weight item, will have different icon and modifier special item will have different icon based on condition, We are looking for dynamic image attaching to item i guess now you understood it correctly

Comment: And why is this a problem? I don't understand why you cannot make this work?

Comment: Thanks it works using FFImageLoading.Cross.MvxCachedImageView

Comment: I highly recommend not to use FFImageLoading, it is unmaintained and has lots of issues.